# OCL - Need some clarification on Invariants?

Tags: ocl

I had a discussion with a professor today on OCL. He believes invariants, post-conditions, and pre-conditions are allowed within the defined contexts of functions.

The software developer in me leads me to want to believe OCL would allow general constraints to be placed on the model. Constraints like All objects of class Person in this model have a sex of male, or all objects of class car have four wheels seem incredible useful and using a declarative paradigm against my model feels right.

I kind of view it like the physical world. If we screw a nut on a bolt the nut is allowed to fit on in one way. These are physical constraints that hold no matter what action we take like screwing the nut on the bolt, and cannot be violated or we have invalidated our model in a fundamental way.

His view is that in OCL we can only define constraints (pre and post conditions/invariants) within functions that are provided a context.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand what do you mean by the contexts of functions. However, OCL goes beyond just invariants/pre/post condition.

From the OMG OCL 2.3.1 specification [1] 7.2.1 *Where to Use OCL*:

OCL can be used for a number of different purposes:

- as a query language,
- **to specify invariants on classes and types in the class model**,
- to specify type invariant for Stereotypes,
- **to describe pre- and post conditions on Operations and Methods**,
- to describe Guards,
- to specify target (sets) for messages and actions,
- to specify constraints on operations, and
- to specify derivation rules for attributes for any expression over a UML model.

So, in other words, you are right, you can have a constraints (not sure what you mean by general) on the model classes like you describe.

[1] http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely define constraints on classes, as you said. You need to clarify what you mean with context though, because you (and your professor) may have misunderstood each other.

OCL has a keyword called context that basically can refer to any UML classifiers (types, classes, interfaces, associations, datatypes, ...).

The example you mention are actually the easiest to address in OCL, through simple expressions such as:

context Person inv:
self.age <= 120

context Person inv:
self.countChildren() <= 20

Answer (score 1):

According to the UML specification (2.5 still beta at the time writing) a Context for a Constraint Context is any NameSpace of a model, classifiers included (Classes). A Constraint can be specified by means of an OpaqueExpression defined, for instance, through the OCL.

As an example consider this post: http://lowcoupling.com/post/57689107913/constraining-uml-models-through-ocl

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, a Constraint may be placed on any UML namespace. However the semantics of invariants is only defined for classes. An invariant defined on a package is unspecified, which is unfortunate since it requires the definition of universal truth (on allInstances()) to be associated with each instance of some class potentially leading to redundant re-evaluation in naive OCL tooling. Look forward to inclusion of package invariants in a future OCL.